# Transactions failing when all conditions are met in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using Stackexchange.Redis on a cluster ASP.Net Core servers, and having some trouble with transactions.

The following code is supposed to delete a field with the key "hashItemID" from two hashes, "HashA" and "HashB", but only if it exists in both:

```
var hashAKey = "HashA";
var hashBKey = "HashB";
var id = "hashItemID";

var tran = redis.Database.CreateTransaction();

// Only delete the item if it exists in both hashes
var hashBCondition = tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashExists(hashBKey, id));
var hashACondition = tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashExists(hashAKey, id));

tran.HashDeleteAsync(hashBKey, id);
tran.HashDeleteAsync(hashAKey, id);

var deleted = await tran.ExecuteAsync();

if (!deleted)
{
    logger.LogWarning("Failed to delete '{ID}'. HashAResult: {A}, HashBResult: {B}", id, hashACondition.WasSatisfied, hashBCondition.WasSatisfied);
}
```

Occasionally this code will fail with the log:

```
Failed to delete 'hashItemID'. HashAResult: True, HashBResult: True
```

I was under the impression that transactions only fail if their conditions aren't met, is that true?

Looking at network and performance metrics, there's no timeouts or high memory usage that could be contributing to this.

Comment: Have you tested this in a single node environment, not a clustered environment? if yes, did you check to see in which nodes do those hashes live in the cluster?

Comment: This is on a single node redis server (AWS ElasticCache to be specific), no clustering. It's the database clients that are clusters (several ASP.Net Core instances).

However, the problem doesn't seem to occur when I limit it to a single ASP.Net Core client, which is weird...

Comment: It sounds like it could be a race-condition on the client side, maybe protect this block with a redis.LockTake, so only execute this if a redis lock is obtained?

Comment: The transaction is completely atomic on redis though isn't it? So there should be no possibility of a race condition there. I should be able to execute that block on the client simultaneously and still have redis process them atomically.

Comment: The transaction is atomic yes but if multiple threads are running at the same time there will be winners and victims.  It's not easy to tell, I ran a multi-threaded test similar to your code and transaction result was always consistent with the conditions met state, only difference is I execute the transaction using Database.Wait(trans.ExecuteAsync()); which would be ridiculous if that's why its working for me ..

Comment: "transactions only fail if their conditions aren't met" - not true. Conditions are evaluated prior to issuing the multi/exec. Any changes to watched keys during the remainder of the transaction will cause an abort, even if the condition would be met if evaluated again.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Unfortunately at higher loads this approach started to fall apart. Sometimes a transaction would require 50 attempts, hurting performance and taking a long time. Still looking for a better solution.

I implemented a workaround that does a good enough job.

In the case of `!deleted && hashACondition.WasSatisfied && hashBCondition.WasSatisfied` I just immediately retry the deletion, up to 4 times.

According to tests, this has mostly fixed it. Of 6000 attempts, 430 needed to be retried once, 62 needed to be retried twice, etc.

This still seems like a bug in redis or stackexchange.redis to me though. It would be nice to hear from someone who knows better than me!

Answer (score -1):

Since I can't add comments because of limits in reputation, You may try this to see if it works for you or not:

```
var hashAKey = "HashA";
var hashBKey = "HashB";
var id = "hashItemID";

var tran = redis.Database.CreateTransaction();

// Only delete the item if it exists in both hashes
var hashBCondition = tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashExists(hashBKey, id));
var hashACondition = tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashExists(hashAKey, id));

tran.HashDeleteAsync(hashBKey, id);
tran.HashDeleteAsync(hashAKey, id);

bool deleted = await tran.ExecuteAsync();

if (!deleted)
{
    logger.LogWarning("Failed to delete '{ID}'. HashAResult: {A}, HashBResult: {B}", id, hashACondition.WasSatisfied, hashBCondition.WasSatisfied);
}
```

Use **bool deleted** instead of var deleted

Comment: I'm sorry, that won't make any difference. `var` is only syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Douglas Can you provide some help for this guy?